# Pandas.get_dummies() single column encoding

Tags: python, pandas

Working with Pandas, and I want to generate dummy variables in place on the data frame I'm working with, but it always generates two columns for binary values. How can I keep it from splitting into columns?

for example: `data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['gender'])` will generate two columns in the place of the gender field. (i.e. `gender_male` and `gender_female` with a 1 representing when the value is true for that record for the column in question.)

I think this is incredibly redundant, but I'm not sure if it matters.

What I would like to know is how to force, or coerce, the `get_dummies()` function to generate a single column where `1 == 'Male'` and `0 == 'Female'`.

what would be the most common/recommended process to do this?

Comment: I believe you're looking for `pd.factorize`. Here's the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html)

Comment: Thats called factorizing. You can simply use `replace` which is even simpler

Comment: `df['gender'].map({
    'Male':1,
    'Female':0
})` ?

Comment: thanks all three of you.